# Unable to load DLL 'xmogrt': from Tridion metadata query

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm trying to use the CustomMetaKeyCriteria class to pull back content from the Broker DB based upon some metadata I set up. However,  I get the error listed below. Any ideas?   That dll is in my bin folder & I confirmed it is the 32 bit version, as this code is running on a 32 bit box. I missed some set up obviously, but what?

> Unable to load DLL 'xmogrt': The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I think at one point there was a missing JAR, but it seems that you need to be careful how the broker api is implemented within a VS.net solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if you have the rest of the dll dependencies for this file?

In my install folder for x86 I see the following DLLs:

- MSVCP71.dll
- MSVCR71.dll
- netrtsn.dll
- Tridion.ContentDelivery.Configuration.dll
- Tridion.ContentDelivery.dll
- Tridion.ContentDelivery.Interop.dll
- xmogrt.dll

EDIT: And the following Tridion jars:

- cd_broker
- cd_cache
- cd_core
- cd_datalayer
- cd_deployer
- cd_linking
- cd_model
- cd_tcdl (not usually needed)

You should probably check cd_core_log for additional details, maybe you're missing one of the 3rd party jars.

Comment: all of those are there.  the error above was when I ran the function in question from a unit test.  I ran that function from the actual project & got this error: "Class not found exception: com.tridion.broker.querying.criteria.metadata.CustomMetaKeyCriteria".  Am I missing a JAR maybe?

Comment: What about a "Could not load file or assembly 'MSVCP71' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest." message?  the error is is "Bad Image format" but I confirmed that I'm using the 32 bit version...

Comment: I guess you are getting the error in an ASP.Net web application. Is that xmogrt.dll in the bin folder of that application, or in the Tridion\bin folder? It should be in the former!

Comment: where can I find the pre-built web app's?

Comment: If you have the installers for "Tridion UI 2012", look in: Tridion UI 2012\Content Delivery\roles\web\dotNET

Comment: I tracked down the files Nuno listed, copied them to my app & still get the 'MSVCP71' error.

Comment: You know, the project in question actually worked until recently, what could have happened?  I'm going to send a note to SDL Support

Comment: You'll probably need more info for Support to be able to help you. If we can't figure it out here... Anyway, this is indeed more for support than SO

Comment: OK, I figured out the step that broke the project.  I added the broker api, added some methods to call the api & called those methods from  a page.  This all worked without any errors.  I then added a unit test.  this is just a sample project so I added a new project for the unit test.  This is when the errors started.  For some reason the broker api has an issue with the unit test project.

Answer (score 3):

Your DLL may be blocked if you copied it from a network location. Try right clicking on the DLL > Properties > Unblock